# How to save full contact from GAL from dist list and save as a private contact in outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, distribution-list

When I open a distribution list and double-click on a member who isn't part of my personal contacts and select add to contacts form the more options menu, it opens up their contact info.  I can then save it to my personal contacts.  Is there a way to do that through VBA so I don't have to click and save each contact individually?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Outlook Object Model, you have no choice put to explicitly create a new contact and copy one property at a time.

If using Redemption is an option, you can call RDOAddressEntry.CopyTo and pass a (newly created) contact as the parameter.

Where does the source address entry come from?